# Using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in a subquery

Tags: mysql

I find that MySQL returns a

```
Incorrect usage/placement of 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS'
```

error if I put SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in a subquery

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
     SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM test_table
  ) as T1
```

Is there a workaround for this? or am I just implementing it incorrectly?

EDIT: There is a reason why I need to make T1 a subquery in case anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using it incorrectly. The `SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND` seems to only apply to outer queries. I'm not sure if this would fit your use case, or if you have additional `WHERE`s in your outer query, but you may be able to do something like this:

> SELECT
>     SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
>   FROM
>     (
>        SELECT * FROM test_table
>     ) as T1 ;
>   SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

The `FOUND_ROWS()` function will give you the total number of rows found before any `LIMIT`s are applied. For more on `FOUND_ROWS()` check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).