# Using an aliased table in multiple PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, subquery, prepared-statement

Due to a need to join multiple tables in a single query, I am not able to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` (or `LIMIT`) on the outer query (the number would be higher than expected).

Here is the ideal query, if MySQL supported using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` within subqueries:

```
SELECT events.*, bands.*
    FROM events
        LEFT JOIN bands ON events.event_id = bands.event_id
    WHERE e.event_id IN (
            SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.event_id
                    FROM events
                    WHERE events.date > NOW()
                    ORDER BY events.date ASC LIMIT 0, 25
            ) ALIAS
    )
ORDER BY events.date ASC
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314392/using-sql-calc-found-rows-in-a-subquery) suggests creating an aliased table, but I am not sure if I can do this with PDO prepared statements.

I attempted this, but got a parse error because FOUND_EVENTS was interpreted as being a (nonexistent) column name:

```
$st1 = $pdo->prepare("(SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.event_id
                            FROM events
                            WHERE events.date > NOW()
                            ORDER BY events.date ASC LIMIT 0, 25
                      ) AS FOUND_EVENTS");

$st2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT events.*, bands.*
                       FROM events
                           LEFT JOIN bands ON events.event_id = bands.event_id
                       WHERE e.event_id IN (
                           FOUND_EVENTS
                       )
                       ORDER BY events.date ASC");

$st1->execute();
$st2->execute();
```

I would prefer to stick to prepared statements if possible, but any working solution would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it in two separate queries.

If your reason for using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is to try and save execution time, you may be surprised to know that in many cases, it will be *much, much* faster, and less load on the database, to use two separate queries instead, one of them with a simple COUNT(*) grouping function to calculate the total rows, and the other one with the LIMIT in place to actually retrieve the rows.

[Here is more explanation of why this is the case](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/).

What's more, if you do it in two separate queries, then you can do the one that actually fetches the rows *first* and then you only need to do the second one with the COUNT(*) if the first one returned the maximum number of rows.

Comment: That's strange that performance would suffer. While performance is not totally crucial to my problem (the result is going to be cached), this does seem like the simplest solution. Thanks!